# NSRange non-continuous string search

Tags: ios, xcode, nsrange

My string is

```
NSString *str= @"Hello Hi How Are You Thank you";
```

If I search "hi how" or "are you" or "thank you" I get result using NSCaseInsensitiveSearch.

```
NSRange r=[searchable rangeOfString:@"hi how" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]

if(r.location!=NSNotFound)

NSLog(@"true");
```

But if I search as "hello how" or "hi you". I don't get any result .

```
NSRange r=[searchable rangeOfString:@"hi you" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]

if(r.location!=NSNotFound)

NSLog(@"true");
```

Please help me to get desired result.

Thanks

Comment: What is your "desired result?"

Comment: Actually I am having lots of string in a array so I am searching and sorting strings containing the words , only continuous search text is giving me desired sorting .
But it should also sort if my entered search text isn't found in continuous manner in the string.

Comment: So if "continuous search text" is giving the desired result, why not use that? Can you please clarify what the output should be or how the array should be sorted? Perhaps more examples would help, in addition to an explanation in .

Comment: For example : first index - a b c      2. a d c     3. a s d f c      Now if I search for " a c "   its result should include all the three index value but it is giving no result but if I search for "a b " it is giving me 1 result .

According to result matched I am adding to a new mutable array and calling it sorted output.
Hope this will clarify the things more .

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want

```
NSString *str= @"Hello Hi How Are You Thank you";

NSRange r1= [str rangeOfString:@"hi" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
NSRange r2 = [str rangeOfString:@"you" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if(r1.location!=NSNotFound && r2.location!=NSNotFound && r2.location > r1.location)
{
    NSLog(@"true");
}
```

Comment: So do you mean I need to break the search text than search for it separately ?

Comment: I need it to return true because the string contain both words "hi" and "you" , but not in continuous way.

Answer (score 0):

What you're actually doing is called "filtering," not "sorting." In Swift, you can implement your desired behavior as follows

```
var stringArray: [NSString] = ["a b c 2", "a d c 3", "a s d f c"]

let filterString = "a c"

stringArray.filter { (element) -> Bool in
    let filterComponents = filterString.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    for component in filterComponents {
        let range = element.rangeOfString(element as String, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        if range.location == NSNotFound {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}

print(stringArray)
```

which will print `[a b c 2, a d c 3, a s d f c]`.

The equivalent code snippet in Objective-C is below.

```
NSArray *stringArray = @[@"a b c 2", @"a d c 3", @"a s d f c"];

NSString *filterString = @"a c";
NSArray *filterComponents = [filterString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *string in stringArray) {
    bool matchesFilter = YES;

    for (NSString *component in filterComponents) {
        NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:component options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
            // don't include in filteredArray
            matchesFilter = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (matchesFilter) {
        [filteredArray addObject:string];
    }

}

NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);
```

which will print `( "a b c 2", "a d c 3", "a s d f c" )`.

Comment: Will this be fast and effective for an array having 4000-5000 indices for filtering ?
I will give a try and will get back to you.

Comment: Possibly. Depends on how many components your `filterString` has. How often do you need to filter?

Comment: Application is completely based on it . User searches for related terms and than selects the cell to view detail of it .

Comment: @arwazshaikh Alright, let me know when you measure the response time of this solution. It it's too slow, we can try to optimize it together. Can you cache the results at all?

Comment: @arwazshaikh Also, if the unfiltered array is constant, you might be able to some preprocessing to speed up filtering.